# Group by in cassandra

Tags: group-by, cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I have a table with 10 million sales data in stores in a csv, which has the following columns (id, date, store, item, unit_sales). I want to know how the table should be created, what field to put in the partition key or if I need a clustering key in cassandra to make the following query:

```
select store, sum (unit_sales) from table group by store
```

I try to create the model of the table in cassandra with the following instruction in CQL latest version in console:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int,
    date date,
    item_nbr int,
    store_nbr int,
    unit_sales decimal,
    PRIMARY KEY (store_nbr));
```

but when migrating the data from my csv to the table with the copy command since there are a lot of data, not all the data is migrated. I do a count and they are not all. also try to do a udf function of aggravation but it takes a long time to make the selection that I tell you. please help

Comment: Can you share a (sanitized is fine) example of a line of data for a record that is inserted on your copy and one that is not?

Comment: the data that is entered with the copy is exactly 53 records of the 10M, this is because there are 53 different types of stores, and the other data are not entered, it is like entering 1 record for each type of store, if I understand ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your primary key, you made store_nbr as PK so if the same PK data repeats it will upsert your existing data. So please add any other key to identify 10M rows as unique then you can see 10M in your cassandra table